# qsort in C with structures, some problems

Tags: c, sorting, struct

```
void sortSchedule (struct event schedule[], int n)
{
    qsort(schedule, n, sizeof(struct event), compare());
}

int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    const struct event *evA = a;
    const struct event *evB = b;

    int startA = evA.start.hour*60 + evA.start.minute;
    int startB = evB.start.hour*60 + evB.start.minute;

    return ( startA - startB );
}
```

My Structure

```
struct tod {
  int hour, minute;
};


struct event {
  struct tod start, end;
};
```

Just using `compare` instead of `compare()`, the compiler seems to treat it as a variable instead.

Secondly, I'm wondering if my compare function is correct? Since i'm getting some errors from the compiler, more specifically the following

`Error: request for member 'start' in something not a structure or union`

^ that error occurs for this line `int startA = evA.start.hour*60 + evA.start.minute;`

So I assume it thinks that evA is not a structure even though I explicitly declared it as such. This might be because I haven't properly declared it, any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: `evA` and `evB` are pointers so you need to dereference with `evA->start`

Comment: I tried that before, and this is the error I got 

`error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'const struct tod')`

Comment: `evA->start.hour*60` start is a struct so you still use `.` for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `evA` and `evB` are pointers, you have to use `evA->member` instead of `evA.member`.

Comment: I tried that before, and this is the error I got 

`error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'const struct tod')`

Comment: Since your members are not pointers, it should look like this: `evA->start.hour`

Comment: Alright, forgot about that. What about the compare issue? Should it be `compare` or `compare()`? The former gives me an error. Secondly, the program seems to crash without much errors coming up on the compiler.

So I removed the two `int startA` and `int startB` lines, and just tried the following, `printf("%d", evA->start.hour);` which also makes the program crash.

Comment: Did you add a _forward declaration_ for your function? The line `int compare(const void * a, const void * b);` should be put somewhere before your call to qsort, e.g. after your #includes. It should then be passed as `compare`, not `compare()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `->` to reference the structure member if you're doing this with pointers:

```
int startA = evA->start.hour*60 + evA->start.minute;
int startB = evB->start.hour*60 + evB->start.minute;
```

And your call to `qsort` should be:

```
qsort(schedule, n, sizeof(struct event), compare);
```

since the fourth argument is a pointer to a function.